# Copying Consolidating Data from Multiple Worksheets into .ActiveWorksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc793964(v=office.12)) article to try and consolidate data from multiple worksheets into a single summary worksheet. I've nearly got it working but I'm struggling to alter the destination worksheet.

I'm trying to have the consolidated data appear into cell `B4` on the `Consolidated Tracker` sheet.

```
 With CopyRng

         Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")
         Set myRange = DestSh.Range("B4")

 End With
```

Problem is myRange is always empty and nothing is copied over.

No error, seems to execute `f8` as expected without copying anything over.

---

Full Code for reference:

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            ' Specify the range to place the data.
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4:B50")

            ' This statement copies values
            With CopyRng
                 Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")
                 Set myRange = DestSh.Range("B4")
            End With

        'End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(4, 2)

    ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet` should only be used when absolutely necessary, and that is *rarely* the case. Use this instead. `Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ScottHoltzman I might be being dumb now (it's been a long day) but I'm trying what you've said with `.Range("B4")` added to the end as I want the data pasted in cell B4 after all but I'm getting a type mismatch error I think because I'm trying to use a cell reference with `DestSh` when it's been set as a Worksheet. I thought .Range would append the cell reference without interacting with the parent variable. Can I never use `DestSh` to specify a cell because it's set as a worksheet?

Comment: You cannot set a worksheet variable to a range object. you need to set a range variable for that. But you can write `DestSh.Range("B4")` directly in the code.

Comment: I've used `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value` elsewhere and it work however I get an invalid use of property error when trying `Set DestSh.Range("B4") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")` thoughts?

Comment: Leave `Set DestSh =  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")` alone. When you want to refer to `B4` in the code write `DestSh.Range("B4")`. For example, ``DestSh.Range("B4").Value = "AValue"` or `Set myRange = DestSh.Range("B4")`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman spent some time playing around, I've updated the OP. It's now sort of working, just nothing is copying over from `Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4:B50")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the code never actually execute any type of command to move the data. The code only sets variables.

Look at the modified code below, specifically the last line before the End With.

```
' Specify the range to place the data.
Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4:B50")

' This statement copies values
With CopyRng
    Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")
    DestSh.Range("B4").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count,1).Value = CopyRng.Value
End With
```